# Unable to pull docker public image into kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have created a basic docker image.And i have pushed the image into the dockerhub and made it public.When i try to download the same image into kubernetes for the deployment it says image cant be pulled , library not found.Can you please help me to sort this issue?

Comment: pls add k8s version, traceback.

Comment: Try logging into the node, and execute docker pull manually. This will show you whethere it's a docker issue or kubelet.